# Testing function throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. Causing test not to pass

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, promise, mocha.js

I played with Mocha Testing. 
I have noticed that my function throws Warring of *"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning"* in few places. It makes the script to do not pass the check.

I could not find useful example on the internet that will teach/show a good way to fix the problem. Maybe one of you can help.

If you have any other comments to my code please feel free to share. I am here to learn :)

Function where the problem occurs.

```
it('/POST /logout => Logout a user by purging a session', (done) => {
        let loginInfo = {};
        loginInfo.usr = 'testuser';
        loginInfo.psw = 'mochatesting197';
        let agent = chai.request.agent(app);
        let json = {};
        json.logout = true;
        agent.post('/login')
            .send(loginInfo)
            .then((res) => {
                return agent.post('/logout')
                    .send(json)
                    .then((res) => {
                        res.should.have.status(200);
                        res.body.should.be.a('object');
                        res.body['success'].should.have.property('message').eql('YOU HAVE LOGGED OUT');
                        done();
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        throw err;
                    });
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning occurs when a Promise is rejected but does not have a catch handler associated with it. Since a handler can be attached to a Promise at any time (even after it is rejected), the default behaviour is to log a warning to the default out (console) after a number of event loop turns.

In the code you supply, the most likely cause is that your catch block is in the wrong place. Try moving the catch handler to the bottom of your Promise chain.

This won't definitely solve the problem, but it's the most likely place within the code you provided. Also, note that when using the 'done' callback mechanism from Mocha, you shouldn't throw. Instead, you should call done with an error (also shown below)

```
it('/POST /logout => Logout a user by purging a session', (done) => {
    let loginInfo = {};
    loginInfo.usr = 'testuser';
    loginInfo.psw = 'mochatesting197';
    let agent = chai.request.agent(app);
    let json = {};
    json.logout = true;
    agent.post('/login')
        .send(loginInfo)
        .then((res) => {
            return agent.post('/logout')
                .send(json)
                .then((res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.body.should.be.a('object');
                    res.body['success'].should.have.property('message').eql('YOU HAVE LOGGED OUT');
                    done();
                })
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            done(err);
        });
});
```

Comment: Great! I will try this tonight :)
I let you know how it went

Comment: It worked fine thanks a lot !
all tho it showed some unwanted 404 errors when expected a 200
but that is a problem for another day